# `simplesamlphp` runs good, how to integrate it with Auth Memcookie?

Tags: php, apache, single-sign-on

`simplesamlphp` makes life in PHP easier, but there really lack documents about how to use it outside PHP.

The Doc. said use Apache Auth Memcookie is ready from 1.0.  And any things can help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official documentation has become available here:
http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-advancedfeatures#section_5